# Hpc does not support c++ 11 what can be done to use c++ 11 library

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, gcc

In our university hpc has redhat based Linux which does not support c++ 11.  S

Comment: Contact the system administrator(s) and explain why you need a C++11 compiler installed (or to get to know where one is already installed). If that fails, ask you course instructor, professor, manager, or similar to talk to the IT department. This is a social problem, not necessarily a technical one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options vary; one could look into [singularity](http://singularity.lbl.gov) which could then run a linux image with suitable C++11 support (among other container or virtualization options), or one could build a software depot that contains the necessary software in a custom tree (e.g. `/opt/mercury` or whatever) though depending on how old the RedHat is that might be a lot of work (and ongoing maintenance) to bootstrap up all the necessary tools, or petition them to upgrade the OS on the HPC platform, or maybe look into cloud provider offerings, etc.